# How to compute subtotal of all items on their property criteria: qty * price?

Tags: javascript

I have an array which represent the item purchases of a customer, and computed the items subtotal in this logic:

```
function getSubtotal(arr) {
  let total = 0.00;
  arr.forEach(function(i) {
    total += (i.qty * i.price)
  });
  return total;  // 1274.21
}
```

And yes of course i get the correct result, but is there any efficient way to do this in javascript?

```js
let data = [
  {
    name : 'Item 1', qty: 2, price: 15.50 // 31
  },
  {
    name : 'Item 2', qty: 17, price: 25.13 // 427.21
  }, 
  {
    name : 'Item 3', qty: 102, price: 8.00 // 816
  }
];

function getSubtotal(arr) {
  let total = 0.00;
  arr.forEach(function(i) {
    total += (i.qty * i.price)
  });
  return total; // 1274.21
}

document.write(getSubtotal(data));
```

Comment: It should be posted on [**CodeReview**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: sorry about that but thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to edit @FrankCamara 's answer but couldn't. So here it is with different formatting:

---

This is one simple way of doing this, using reduce.

```js
let data = [
  {
    name : 'Item 1', qty: 2, price: 15.50 // 31
  },
  {
    name : 'Item 2', qty: 17, price: 25.13 // 427.21
  }, 
  {
    name : 'Item 3', qty: 102, price: 8.00 // 816
  }
];

function getSubTotal (items) {
  const fn = (total, { price, qty }) => total + price * qty;
  
  return items.reduce(fn, 0);
}

console.log(getSubTotal(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one simple way of doing this, using reduce.

```
function getSubtotal (arr) {
  return arr.reduce((total, obj) => {
    return total + obj.qty * obj.price;
  }, 0);
}
```

which can be written like this

```
function getSubtotal (arr) {
  return arr.reduce((total, obj) => total + obj.qty * obj.price, 0);
}
```

or

```
return arr.reduce((total, {qty, price}) => total + qty * price, 0);
```

Comment: Well its really simple :)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is another solution using `map`**

```
var Data = [
  {name : 'Item 1', qty: 2, price: 15.50},
  {name : 'Item 2', qty: 17, price: 25.13}, 
  {name : 'Item 3', qty: 102, price: 8.00}
];

var total = 0;
var reformattedArray = Data.map(function(obj) {
   total+=obj.qty*obj.price;
   return total;
});

console.log(total); /*Sum of all qty*price`*/
console.log(reformattedArray); /*Sum of its and previous index as an array*/
console.log(reformattedArray[reformattedArray.length-1]); /*SubTotal, Last Index*/
```

**Result of** `console.log(total)`;

```
1274.21
```

**Result of** `console.log(reformattedArray)`;

```
[
  31,       /* (2*15.50) */
  458.21,   /* (2*15.50)+(17*25.13) */
  1274.21   /* (2*15.50)+(17*25.13)+(102*8.00) */
]
```

**Result of** `console.log(reformattedArray[reformattedArray.length-1])`;

```
1274.21
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `for` loop is more faster that `forEach` and `reduce`. Here is a test demo.

```js
let data = [{
  name: 'Item 1',
  qty: 2,
  price: 15.50 // 31
}, {
  name: 'Item 2',
  qty: 17,
  price: 25.13 // 427.21
}, {
  name: 'Item 3',
  qty: 102,
  price: 8.00 // 816
}];

function getSubtotalReduce(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((total, item) => total + item.qty * item.price, 0.00);
}
console.time('reduce');
console.log(getSubtotalReduce(data));
console.timeEnd('reduce');


function getSubtotal(arr) {
  let total = 0.00;
  arr.forEach(function(i) {
    total += (i.qty * i.price)
  });
  return total; // 1274.21
}

console.time('forEach');
console.log(getSubtotal(data));
console.timeEnd('forEach');

function getTotalFor(data) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    total += data[i].qty * data[i].price;
  }
  return total;
}

console.time('for');
console.log(getTotalFor(data));
console.timeEnd('for');
```

Source: [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158491/computing-the-subtotal-of-all-items-on-their-property-criteria-qty-price/158501#158501)